# xcalib unable to read file ''

Tags: bash, shell

When trying to use the xcalib tool to adjust the screens color and resolution such as...

```
xcalib -red 1.1 10.0 100.0
```

I get the error

```
Warning - Unable to read file ''
```

The error started after adding the xorg .conf file

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

before adding this I was getting an error

```
Error-unsupported ramp size 0
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: That was my mistake, had to many tabs open!